# How to stream data on UDP Socket

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I know how to open a UDP socket server/client and transmit one data at a time, ie the CPU temp of my Raspberry, with Python3 using this code:

**Client:**

```
# ----- An UDP client in Python that sends temperature values to server-----

import socket
import time

# Get Raspberry's CPU temperature

def getTemp():
        temp = int(open('/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp').read())
        return temp;

# A tuple with server ip and port

serverAddress = ("127.0.0.1", 7070);

# Create a datagram socket

tempSensorSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM);

# Get temperature
# while True:
temperature = int(open('/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp').read())
tempString  = "%.2f"%temperature;

# Socket is not in connected state yet...sendto() can be used
# Send temperature to the server

tempSensorSocket.sendto(tempString.encode(), ("127.0.0.1",7070));
```

**Server:**

```
# ----- An UDP server in Python that receives temperature values from clients-----

import socket
import datetime


# Define the IP address and the Port Number
ip      = "127.0.0.1";
port    = 7070;

listeningAddress = (ip, port);

# Create a datagram based server socket that uses IPv4 addressing scheme
datagramSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM);
datagramSocket.bind(listeningAddress);

while(True):
    tempVal, sourceAddress = datagramSocket.recvfrom(128);
    print("Temperature at %s is %s"%(sourceAddress, tempVal.decode()));
    response = "Received at: %s"%datetime.datetime.now();
    datagramSocket.sendto(response.encode(), sourceAddress);
```

What I don't know is how to send a **constant flow of data** (*Raspberry CPU's temps*) between the client and the server.

In other words: every time I launch `client.py`, I see on the server the actual Raspberry's CPU temperature, but I don't know how to launch the client and view on the server side the **continuous change, in realtime,** of the Raspberry's CPU temp.

Any idea?

Comment: Just run the client code in a loop. Possibly with a pause between sends. I see you have `# while True:` in the client. Why did you comment that out?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of programs that can do this already (e. g. [Pi Control](https://pi-control.de/) or [Webmin](https://webmin.com/)), so I probably wouldn't do this myself.

To answer your question: There are two possibilities: You could send the temperature multiple times inside the script or you could call the script multiple times.

First option:

```py
# ----- An UDP client in Python that sends temperature values to server-----

import socket
import time

# Get Raspberry's CPU temperature

def getTemp():
        temp = int(open('/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp').read())
        return temp;

# A tuple with server ip and port

serverAddress = ("127.0.0.1", 7070);

# Create a datagram socket

tempSensorSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM);

while True:
    # Get temperature
    # while True:
    temperature = int(open('/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp').read())
    tempString  = "%.2f"%temperature;

    # Socket is not in connected state yet...sendto() can be used
    # Send temperature to the server

    tempSensorSocket.sendto(tempString.encode(), ("127.0.0.1",7070));

    time.sleep(30) # seconds
```

(Python doesn't require semicolons, why did you use them?)

Second option (using [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)):

`$ crontab -e`

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/client.py
```

This runs the script every minute.

Comment: Hi. anonymous...Thanks for your reply. After I've published my post I realized that in the code was an identation error on the tempSensorSocket.sendto(tempString.encode(), ("127.0.0.1",7070)) . The while true loops works fine. Thanks. P.S. I don't know why there was semicolon in the script